# spaceAround command does not work in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
Column(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: TextFormWidget(
              form: name,
              hint: 'Name',
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 15,
          ),
          TextFormWidget(form: surname, hint: 'Surname'),
          const Spacer(
            flex: 3,
          ),
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: const [
              CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                    'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTMBCFcTbfwsRUXmYHZYKW6x2kWZWQfxbcbIMxsC1eA9pz6irVCIlzrg-I0UK1B-8zQbag&usqp=CAU'),
              ),
              EditBTN(),
            ],
          ),
          const Spacer(),
        ],
      ),
```

[image]

I want to show the CircleAvatar seen in the image in the middle of the page. When I give the spaceAraound command to the Column that contains the button and CircleAvatar I created, there is no change.

Answer (score 0):

From the Spacer flutter documentation:

> The Spacer widget will take up any available space, so setting the Flex.mainAxisAlignment on a flex container that contains a Spacer to MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround, MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, or MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly will not have any visible effect: the Spacer has taken up all of the additional space, therefore there is none left to redistribute.

You're using a Spacer to distribute the space. Consider either wrapping every other element in the `Column` with a flex widget like `Expanded`/`Flex`, or get rid of the Spacer and use another way to add space.

Once that is done, you will have a better chance of seeing space between your elements.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `Spacer` widgets you are using inside the in the top and bottom of the `Column`, they are taking all the space above and under it, so no space to be taken around the widgets of the `Column`, the solution is to remove them and wrap the `Column` with an `Expanded` widget so that the `Column` can take all the available space and just put it around the widgets in the `Column`.

So the modified snippet could be:

```
Column(
  children: [
    Center(
      child: TextFormWidget(
        form: name,
        hint: 'Name',
      ),
    ),
    const SizedBox(
      height: 15,
    ),
    TextFormWidget(form: surname, hint: 'Surname'),
    Expanded(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTMBCFcTbfwsRUXmYHZYKW6x2kWZWQfxbcbIMxsC1eA9pz6irVCIlzrg-I0UK1B-8zQbag&usqp=CAU'),
          ),
          EditBTN(),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```